# remove if data in array falsy in javascript

Tags: javascript

falsy javscript

```
const value = ''
const example = [5,!!value&&value]

expectation result is [5]
reality result is [5,false]
```

is there any other way to check falsy in javascript ? I want to set the value is the value is valid

Comment: The value of !!value&&value is `false`, and that's a valid value for an array item. You want to filter it out? Look into Array.filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use spread operator like this
for example

```
const value = "test"
[5, ...value]
```

Comment: Hi @Joo. This wont work if value as null value, or is a string :)

Try [5, ...'test']

Comment: Thanks  @Poyoman i updated my answer to reduce some ambiguous

Comment: Hey @Joo -- your edits don't address the issue @Poyoman brought up. Did you try running your code with a null `value`?

Answer (score 3):

You can have several approaches.

1. Post-filter your array

   `[5, value].filter((v) => v)`
2. Use spread opperator

   `[5, ...value ? [value] : []]`
3. Add conditionally

   `const example = [5]; value && example.push(value);`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const value = '';
const example = [5, value].filter((x) => !!x);
console.log(example)
```

You can use the array function `filter` to return an array with only the truthy values.
This will give you [5].

Alternatively, if you are using es6, you can use the spread syntax to get the same result:

```js
const value = '';
const example = [5, ...(value ? [value] : [])];
console.log(example)
```

Here we are spreading the result of a ternary. If the value is truthy, we give an array with the value inside it, otherwise we give an empty array.

Note, you may need babel to use es6 syntax depending on your target browsers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `every()` method to iterate over the array, convert each value to boolean, negate it, and return the result. If all values in the array are falsy, the every method will return true.

```
function CheckIfHasFalsy(arr) {
  return arr.every(element => !element);
}

console.log(CheckIfHasFalsy([5, '', false])); // true
console.log(CheckIfHasFalsy([5, 'test', true])); // false
```

And This one remove falsy value from array:

```
myArray = [1, '', true]
var myFilterArray = myArray.filter(Boolean);
```